# QWebView which version of webkit supported?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtwebkit

I am new to Qt. What I understand is Qt is porting webview from webkit. [Correct me if i am wrong].  and I could not able to find which version of the webkit is ported into Qt 5.0 or higher version.

Kindly suggest me how to find?

Answer (score 0):

It's running on WebKit2, which specific version is a bit more tricky to find out, but you should be able to look through the Qt repository on gitorious to determine it. If I remember rightly it changes depending on how you've built Qt5 and where from.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a 3-4 months old snapshot, see the [git repo](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtwebkit/commits/stable) for the included commits.